# Azure Botframework: How to re-prompt the Prompt.text if user responds with invalid value

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a single `dialog` which has multiple Prompts(`Prompts.text`, `Prompts.number`, `Prompts.Choice`, `Prompts.confirm`). Though `Prompts.choice` and `Prompts.confirm` seems to have inbuilt validations but how to validate `Prompts.text`?

I have gone through this thread [How to handle wrong input from the user?](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1437) but it was rectified by converting text into choice.

Also I do not want to restart the whole dialog as it ask the questions form beginning then as shown in [create custom prompts to validate input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-replace)

Here is shorter version for my dialog:

```
bot.dialog('/getDetails', [

 function (session, args, next) {

    let options = {
                retryPrompt: 'The response id invalid'
                }

      builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What is your full name?', options);
     //passing options as argument works for Prompts.choice, which seems an inbuilt validation

 },
 function (session, results, next){

     var name = session.dialogData.name;

     //How to to reprompt if user does not enters its full name?
     if (results.response) {
         name.fullname = results.response;
     }

       builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Can you please provide your country name?');  

 },
 function (session, results) {

     var name = session.dialogData.name;

     //How to reprompt only last Prompts.text if user enter an invlid value?
     if (results.response) {
         name.text = results.response;
     }

    }
 }]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'GetDetails', 
})
```

Comment: Check replaceDialog function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i solved it through [DialogAction.validatedPrompt](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.dialogaction.html#validatedprompt)

```
bot.dialog('/getDetail', [
    function (session) {
      session.beginDialog('/validateAge', { prompt: "What's your age?" });

      //if false response, then prmopts "I did not understand {age}""    

    },
    function (session, results) {

        if (results.response) {
            session.send("Thank you for adding your age");
        } 
    }
]).triggerAction({
     matches: /^lets validate$/i

})


bot.dialog('/validateAge', builder.DialogAction.validatedPrompt(builder.PromptType.text, function (response) {
   if(response> 0 && response < 70){

    return response;
   }
}));
```